# Как очистить(скрыть) только что введенную строчку в консоли C#

Tags: c#

Мой первый вопрос на этой площадке.

Как очистить(скрыть) только что введенную информацию в консоль, не стирая при этом все что было выведено в консоль до момента ввода?

```
        Console.WriteLine("ДЗ Заполнить массив с клавиатуры");
        Console.WriteLine("Введите количество элементов массива");

        string[] arrayData;
        int arrayAmount = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        arrayData = new string[arrayAmount];
        Console.WriteLine("Введите элемент массива");

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayAmount; i++)
        {
            arrayData[i] = Console.ReadLine();//хочу чтобы эти данные после ввода не отображались в консоли
            
        }

        Console.WriteLine("Ваш массив включает:");

        for (int i = 0; i < arrayData.Length; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Элемент массива № " + i + " содержит: " + arrayData[i]);
        }
```

Answer (score 4):

Один из простых способов "очистить" строку таков:

```
Console.Write("\r" + new string(' ', Console.BufferWidth) + "\r");
```

Но, так как `Console.ReadLine()` делает переход на новую строку, перед тем очистить строку, нужно на неё вернутся:

```
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
```

Пример:

```
Console.WriteLine("Hello World 1");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World 2");
Console.SetCursorPosition(0, Console.CursorTop - 1);
Console.Write("\r" + new string(' ', Console.BufferWidth) + "\r");
Console.WriteLine("Hello World 3");
```

Вывод в консоль:

```
Hello World 1
Hello World 3
```

*Взято из ответов на [аналогичный вопрос](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8946808/can-console-clear-be-used-to-only-clear-a-line-instead-of-whole-console) с англоязычной ветки stack**overflow**.*

Comment: Спасибо за ответ. Попробую.

Comment: Работает, но строка продолжает занимать место в консоли, хоть и не отображает информацию

Comment: @LikeTonyFerguson ну так сделайте SetCursorPosition на строчку выше еще раз

Comment: не забудь поставить галочку ответу